# Audit in which I was unable to act?

Tags: support, bug, review-audits, link-only-answers

I just ran on review audit.
I couldn't comment nor edit (I really just wanted to comment, and it was just what was in this comment on the picture below). I don't see a point in downvoting this kind of answer since it can be edited.

I've choosed *No action needed*.
I don't see a point using this kind of audits if I can't do what I intended. After this I'm losing my will. :/

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Edit: One more thing. Explanation of my missing yet required actions is pointing me in a first place for an edit. *This post is deleted and cannot be edited.* I really think someone needs to remove this specific audit or fix it.

Edit #2: My bottom line - anyone of you readers don't think that comment this post is useful enough for action in this review queue?

Comment: What you actually don't understand from **STOP Look and Listen**?

Comment: Smart guy, I was paying attention. Isn't it clear from my post?

Comment: It looks as a spam post to me... [this is the audit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5831848) ... it is not an answer...The text from the article needs to be in the post

Comment: @rene - From http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta :  How does it work? -> asking questions about how the websites work, asking questions of the community, posting bugs, suggesting improvements.

Comment: @Miki The actions intended to be taken from your side on this review are clearly stated there. Are you smart enough to find them? _No action needed_ wasn't one of them :P ...

Comment: Uhuh? I'm perfectly aware how meta works, thank you.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ - I couldn't comment!

Comment: @rene - if you are perfectly aware then you're just teasing me. It's not nice.

Comment: @Miki _"I couldn't comment!"_ That also won't have been the right reaction.

Comment: You guys made me add another tag. :p

Comment: You made me LOL...

Comment: Could you explain why you couldn't comment or edit?  Were neither of those options available?

Comment: No, they were available, but comment didn't react on clicking and edit lead me to page with note that post isn't available anymore.

Comment: @Miki not sure why commenting wasn't available, I get that option when reviewing in the same queue.  But when you tried to edit and were told that the question wasn't available should have been a red flag that the post was an audit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 - agree with you.

Answer (score 7):

You failed [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5831848) because you choose 'No action needed'.

The post you were presented is of low quality becuase it doesn't answer the question, it gives a link. Link only answers are [not good answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer), are flagged by users and then deleted.

You should have flagged the post instead and/or downvote it.

Remember that flagging only puts the post in the appropiate queue for other users to review. Moderators are only involved when you choose the *Other* flag-option.

When flags are handled in the Low Quality Queue pre-canned comments are send to the inbox of the user and visible under the post, even after deletion, so the OP gets informed about the reason the post is deleted.

Comment: rene, I don't think I should only flag this question. Flagging is pointing to moderators that something is wrong. It is better approach to warn post author to improve the answer. After all, this was a First post queue. Did I missed something or this queue was intended as some kind of help for newcomers?

Comment: What is a misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah, I get it now after your edit

Comment: @rene did something change?  AFAIK flags do not come with pre-canned comments.  The pre-canned comments originate from the Low Quality Posts queue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 no, you're right that is what I meant to say but didn't...

Answer (score 7):

If you've ever browsed the low quality queue and voted to delete, you might have seen the following reason:

> **This is a link-only answer (and not spam)**
>
> “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the
>   essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.
>   Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

The existence of that close reason suggests that the post you were reviewing probably should be flagged, or if you didn't want to take as much risk, it could probably have been downvoted too.

Comment: My idea was to comment post so that author could improve it.