# Advice on a failed audit

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I just failed a First Posts review on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25713067/vector-direction-for-gravity-in-a-circular-orbit), for which I said it was too broad. To me, it's a broad "what algorithms/calculations could I use here" type question with an overly detailed example to go along with it.  It literally takes over 1,500 characters to get to a '?'.  As it stands, I thought it was too broad.  If everyone generally agrees that it is definitely a good question, albeit a little long, I may just choose to skip questions like this in the future (which I very rarely do).  I enjoy reviewing questions as much as I do asking and answering, so I want to make sure I've got this right going forward.

Comment: Its a wall of text, but not a terrible question. There's an awful lot of noise there and it probably should be edited, but I wouldn't have voted to close it.

Comment: Basically its not a bad question, but probably not a good audit question.

Comment: What actions were actually suggested in the **STOP, Look and listen** message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Audit in which I was unable to act?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271905/audit-in-which-i-was-unable-to-act)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it recommended upvoting, which I don't think I'd ever do to wall of text questions like this. I'm thinking "skip" was the right choice for me now.

Answer (score 3):

> It literally takes over 1,500 characters to get to a '?'

That doesn't mean it's too broad, which implies that the question lacks specificity (or even the ability to focus on a single problem). If anything, this question errs in the other direction, perhaps because - as the author notes - he'd previously asked a question that *was* overly-broad and wished to avoid making that mistake again.

Wouldn't it suck to put all that work into avoiding a specific mistake, only to have someone survey your efforts and decide you'd written too much to bother reading and shut it down *again?*

This is why we have audits. Consider this a lesson for the future!