# I couldn't leave a comment on a Review Audit item

Tags: support, bug, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I don't know if this is a bug or desired result, but I have just failed a review audit but I couldn't do what I wanted to, which was leave a comment on a user's first question saying that the subject was quite broad, but if they posted some code of what they tried then perhaps we could help.

I tried to click on 'add comment' a few times, but the box failed to open, and the page seemed to reload the whole content. In hindsight I should have attempted to flag the question as too broad, but instead I moved onto the next item in the review queue. Obviously I was then given the fail on the audit as the question was of low quality, but I did try!

I didn't fail by clicking "add comment". The possible bug is not being able to comment. It's my fault that I failed.

The *bug* was reproduced by Pokechu22, as you can see in the comments below, so it's not just me.

Is this a known issue, or is it expected behaviour?

Comment: I think they changed the audit process to make it impossible to add a comment on audit questions. If this happens assume it's an audit and take the appropriate action.

Comment: @eddie_cat You could be right, but one of the things that it was suggested I could have done to pass the review was to leave a comment that helped the user. It seems a bit unfair.

Comment: I totally agree, in that case I am guessing I am wrong and maybe there's a bug (or they just didn't change the appropriate text to reflect the new procedure). Personally I think that commenting should be removed completely from the audit process as an option, or it should not count as a review action at all.

Comment: `...but instead I moved onto the next item in the review queue`.  You obviously thought something was wrong, but you still clicked "No Action Needed".  That's a problem.  "No Action Needed" should rarely be used for posts that are acceptable but not quite good enough to upvote and not quite bad enough to downvote.  Not being able to comment is odd as you aren't the first person I've seen report such an issue, but I have tried it any not seen a problem.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I know why I failed, my point was the commenting. If I was able to comment, however, I would (probably) not have failed.

Comment: @worldofjr and I addressed that in my last sentence.  I tried to comment on an audit successfully in the recent past and did so successfully.  But I have [seen at least one other user](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271905/250725) complain about not being able to comment on an audit.

Comment: @psubsee2003 I can confirm that I am unable to comment in audits (at least ones that were low-quality).  My browser is `Internet Explorer 11`, `Version 11.0.9600.17278` (`Update 11.0.12, KB2977629`).  (And before people say I should switch, I just am unable to do so for technical reasons)

Comment: Except it isn't as I didn't fail by clicking "add comment". The possible bug is not being able to comment. It's my fault that I failed.

Comment: @Pokechu22, I see you're using the lame Internet Explorer, you should totally drop that and try jquery.

Answer (score -1):

I hit the same bug on an audit question (this audit: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10282834)

Well the current error is completely nonsensical (thus I believe bug -- that is WHATEVER the intended behavior, the current behavior is wrong due to a bad error message), but what to do is open to speculation. Personally I feel you might as well give up at this point and reveal it's an audit question. Anybody who hits this once will know the second time anyway.

Comment: Any reason for linking the question instead of the audit? Or for making your answer CW?

Comment: I set it CW because it's not really an answer. I didn't know you could link to an audit so I didn't try.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/10282834

Comment: And if you try it now the message reads "This is an audit."