# This post is deleted and cannot be edited (review audits)

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, first-post-review

This question is similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/359888/page-for-editing-a-deleted-post-for-users-with-less-than-10k-reputation). I came across a review audit when reviewing "First Posts", and the answer was in another language. I clicked to edit it, thinking that I could translate it. However, the "edit" link just directs me to this page:

[image]

This page does not make much sense. I suggest that instead, when a user clicks "edit" on a review audit, they should automatically pass the audit, because it shows that the user was paying attention.

Comment: If memory serves, there's a really unexpected subtlety to this. There's a previous post about this somewhere, I'll see if I can find it.

Comment: Please review [this FAQ about translating posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content/297680#297680). Sorry, @Shog9 if I stole your thunder :).

Comment: No, that's a whole tangential discussion @Mike; there's a legit bug here, I just can't remember what triggers it.

Comment: @Shog9 probably something to do with audits.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's what's going on:

1. First Posts and Late Answers review queues allow users to edit "in place" - clicking "edit" shows an inline editor. You can also open the full editor in a new tab, but this doesn't "count" toward the review unless you refresh the review page after submitting the edit.
2. Audits in these queues have to mock up tools so that you don't inadvertently mess with real posts on the site (which, for deleted posts, would fail anyway). For the edit feature, this *immediately* passes the audit so as not to waste unnecessary time allowing you to write an edit that will only be discarded.
3. Turns out, #2 doesn't happen if you have under 2K reputation; the edit link remains only a link to the full edit page, with no script connecting it to the audit.

It looks very much as though I first realized this [almost four years ago now](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275316/lame-stop-look-and-listen-even-though-i-tried-to-edit-a-bad-post/275550#275550); even though several of the previous reports that I linked to *then* were marked fixed, that report wasn't - and of course, it's still happening today.

The root cause here was a little look-up table used for wiring up tools when the current review task is an audit. It omitted an entry for the suggest-edit link... Leaving it to be entirely ignored by both the review and the audit logic.

Comment: Why can't people fix this?

Comment: I think I tracked down the root cause this time, @xcoder - I'll see if I can get a fix in.

Comment: Fixed now, @Xcoder

Comment: Ok, sounds good :)