# Your review was inappropriate - sorry, but it wasn't

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I got into the world of reviewing posts and this shows up:

> "STOP! Look and Listen.
>   This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting."

This happened immediately after I pressed the edit button. The question had 17 upvotes. Why did I press edit? It was a question completely unrelated to excel-vba, and yet it had the [excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel-vba) tag.

Then I checked the post, and it didn't have the tag.

[Here is the review item](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/19750955).

Please, when you test reviewers, show things as they are in the real post.

Comment: Sorry, I got so mad by this that I haven't expressed myself clearly. I have just corrected my post. I was actually reviewing posts in First Posts queue. As I've just started, I usually just skip and do what I am completely sure is a full, good edition. I clicked "edit" on the question when in review mode.

Comment: They saw it *from* review, @psubsee2003. Probably the First Posts queue; I fixed a bug there recently that prevented edits from working for folks < 2K, which means... It's now working as designed, and I may not have picked the best design.

Comment: @RyszardJędraszyk: "*Please, when you test reviewers, show things as they are in real post.*" Review audits have to be shown in the state they were originally presented for review. The goal is to make sure you choose the same thing the original reviewer did.

Comment: @NicolBolas the audits never use previous reviews to evaluate whenever you pass or not, but takes from a list of known good/bad post (based on several criteria) and presents those to the reviewer. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/157172/213575

Comment: @NicolBolas That isn't the case for every audit & filter combination, SO sometimes adds the tag you filtered on onto the question, and then expects you to know its an audit

Comment: Pragmatic advice about dealing with the system as it stands: a single failure doesn't have any negative consequences for you at all, and now that you've had one you'll quickly learn to sniff out audits simply from the presence of obviously inappropriate tags (which should provoke you to open up the question outside review, notice the absence of the tag, and realise you're being lied to). Obviously, that's not to say that this is good design, nor to invalidate the perfectly natural human response of being indignant about receiving a scolding when you've in fact done nothing wrong.

Comment: Pragmatic advice about dealing with the system as it stands: Stop reviewing.

Comment: @dasdingonesin no, don't stop reviewing, Stack Overflow needs a lot of reviewers (think of the Close Votes review queue).

Comment: @Cœur Stack Overflow needs a lot of reviewers, yet insults the reviewers' intelligence with this completely asinine audit system. _"you'll quickly learn to sniff out audits simply from the presence of obviously inappropriate tags (which should provoke you to open up the question outside review, notice the absence of the tag, and realise you're being lied to)"_ – I guess everyone needs to determine for themselves if they want to waste their time on "sniff[ing] out audits".

Comment: @Shog9  If even an 'author' of the audit would've failed it 10/10 times then it means audit it broken :)

Comment: Honestly they need auditors to audit the audits. Generate 1k of them, have all the mods review them, then use the ones that pass muster. Do that every quarter.

Comment: _"STOP! Look and Listen_ sounds unnecessarily rude

Comment: honestly, I think the worst part about this is the assumption that because a question is known to be good that there's no valid reason to edit an improvement in.

Comment: @LuisMendo I would guess that it comes from the [Stop, Look, & Listen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z7M3uFaJ8K4) children's educational program, not sure if that makes it more or less rude/insulting but it is probably a failed attempt at humor.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks, I wasn't aware of that reference (not a native English speaker). I guess that softens it a bit, but still rude

Comment: @LuisMendo The audits are meant to stop robo-reviewers so the message is trying to stop someone who's been hammering a button rushing through reviews from dismissing the failure notice without actually reading (or even noticing) it.

Comment: @DanNeely That should be a feature request if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: @BSMP: That's not an issue for a feature request. It is a clear bug. If the audit system randomly adds unrelated tags to an audit question, the audit system **knows** that there is a valid reason to edit the post. I understand the necessity for reviews, and I understand why audits are required. Still, the system in its current state has been rendered virtually useless. The OP didn't just do anything wrong. They *actively* did the **Right Thing**. And get called on for it. There's something severely wrong with this picture.

Comment: @IInspectable **I'm not saying the OP did something wrong.** I suggested a feature request because it seems to be intended behavior that should be changed as opposed to it doing something they didn't mean for it to do.

Comment: @BSMP: Failing an audit due to an edit on a post the system *full well* **knows** to ***require editing*** cannot possibly be intended behavior.

Comment: @BSMP Sure. But the audits may fail, so the reviewer may not actually deserve a rude statement like that

Comment: @LuisMendo I'm not sure there is a polite way to ask someone to immediately stop since that requires yelling at some level. Someone suggested disabling the buttons for a few seconds (forcing a user to stop instead of yelling at them to) but I can't recall what the reasoning against that was.

Comment: @Will: Yeah, [I thought of that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284412/manual-audit-validation-to-create-highly-reusable-unambiguous-audits), but it didn't fly.

Comment: @IInspectable You're not supposed to edit trash that needs to be chucked in the bin, so editing an unrecoverable question can be considered to be an incorrect action.

Comment: @Will: I will disagree with that statement. I've seen edits to trash posts, that turned them into valid and even good questions or answers (without altering the intent of the original author). But that is completely irrelevant here: The OP was (rightfully) trying to edit a *modified* post, that was assumed to be good by the system. Regardless, this has been [acknowledged as a bug](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368118/1889329), and it is being addressed.

Comment: Never been a fan of the "tests" as for me they're effectively a waste of my time, but the moderators seem to think they do a lot of good.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

So... This is actually a bug.

I'll explain why in a minute, but first I need to apologize - my memory of how this stuff works has gotten a little bit unreliable after 6 years. I recalled that we'd implemented edits as failures at one point, but kinda forgot about... Well, a lot of what happened after that.

See, turns out we've had this discussion before. Editing is kind of a dodgy thing to try & classify as a "positive" or "negative" action, particularly in queues where you're not being asked to identify *really horrible things* like spam.

So, 5 years ago - about 4 months after we first introduced audits - we changed how audits interpret these responses: if you try to edit spam, you fail; if you try to edit anything else, you pass.

And, sure enough, that's how it works to this day.

...except, well... We kinda forgot about suggested edits.

I mean *completely* forgot about them. For years, they just didn't work at all in the First Posts and Late Answers queues. You wouldn't fail *or* pass an audit, you'd just end up kicked out of review and on the normal edit page. [Until 10 days ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275316/lame-stop-look-and-listen-even-though-i-tried-to-edit-a-bad-post/275550#275550), when I got the bright idea of making suggested edits actually, y'know, do something for an audit.

Unfortunately, I didn't bother checking to see if what it would do was correct. I tested it, saw that it failed for "known-good", and vaguely remembered that being the correct behavior at one point without recalling why that turned out to be a terrible idea...

...which is how you got what you saw yesterday: the bit of code responsible for determining how an edit should be treated in response to an audit checked the response for the edit flag, but completely ignored the suggested edit flag, which caused it to fall back on the default behavior: which just so happens to treat edits as failing everything.

As a result of my oversight, 62 audits have unnecessarily failed over the past 10 days, potentially contributing to the temporary bans from review of up to 24 reviewers. I've submitted a patch to correct the problem, and will be going through the history of these audits to lift any bans that were unfairly applied.

Please accept my sincere apology for the mistake and gratitude for bringing this to our attention.

Comment: Give that man a snickers!

Comment: So, to clarify, clicking "edit" on an audit should always pass now, correct? In any queue with the "edit" option?

Comment: Unless the audit is based on a confirmed spam post, @TylerH.

Answer (score 27):

If the audit system can't find an audit question with tags matching your filters, it picks a random question and adds bogus tags to avoid tipping you off.  If you try to remove the bogus tag, you fail.

I agree that it's insulting to be told you failed a review when you were attempting to correct a genuine problem with the post.  Arguably, you should have been failed for the opposite reason.  Some possible solutions that come to mind:

- Only fail the audit after it's clear that the reviewer is doing more than removing spurious tags.
- Don't fail the audit for any kind of edit.  Assume in good faith that if the reviewer is editing the question then the No answer is perfect, so why fail the reviwer for trying to add  maybe the reviewer is an expert on the subject and has useful information to add.  This might also be a good opportunity to stop [failing audits for commenting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260803/review-audit-failed-after-just-clicking-add-comment).
- Hide audit question tags completely in cases where they would currently be fabricated, as well as on a small percentage of non-audit questions.  Tags would still be shown on audit questions where they match the reviewer's filters, so the presence or absence of tags doesn't reveal if the question is an audit.

In the mean time until this is fixed, either don't use tag filters or double-check the question before editing out an obviously mistaken tag.

Dear SO dev team: I understand that you add extra tags to avoid tipping reviewers off to the audit, but it's just not right to yell at people for fixing a genuine problem.  By doing that you're training users to sniff out audits and behave differently.  I suggest you comment out the "tag fabrication" code *right now* and leave it that way until a better solution can be found/implemented.  @Lamac made some insightful comments on this subject.

Comment: *"you know better and can safely ignore it"* - Unfortunately, you cannot. The robot doesn't know that it was in error. It will treat the good folks like everyone else, who is failing an audit because they are rushing through reviews, in a hurry, to cash in some easy rep before breakfast.

Comment: Another option would be, you know, not adding bogus tags

Comment: I suppose you do get banned from reviewing, if you fail too many audits. I haven't been there so I cannot say for sure, but I think that's part of the implemented protection scheme.

Comment: @IInspectable I did some quick searching and it looks like you're right.  Audit fails can get you banned, at least temporarily.  I edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: @Lamak Not adding bogus tags would make it easy for crafty users to pick out reviews.  Still, I agree that would be much better than yelling people for fixing a legitimate problem with the post.  Will edit to incorporate your suggestion.

Comment: @BonsaiOak why?, as you say in your post, the fact that there are "unrelated" bogus tags make it easy to spot it's a review

Comment: @Lamak I see your point.

Comment: See this is why I don't waste my time on things that companies should hire employees for... wait, why am I wasting my time commenting here?

Comment: In the Close Votes review queue, I learned that the Edit button is my safe bet against questions that I suspect are just audits. Why this would result in a fail in the First Posts queue is beyond me. I have to agree that sticking the filtered tag in a random question is utterly artificial, and treating this particular case as a bug should be the right way to go.

Comment: @E_net4: [One shouldn't fail an audit immediately if one clicks on edit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/283179/1889329) explains, why the system works this way.

Comment: This answer poses a deep philosophical conundrum: it is possible to be insulted by a computer?

Answer (score 10):

I'm not an expert on statistics in any way, so I am going out on a limb here. But something appears to be fundamentally wrong with the way the audit system works.

Presumably, audit candidates are picked based on statistical data, and the set of admissible actions is based on that data. The statistical data is only meaningful in context of the setup it was gathered from.

Now the audit system comes around, changes the post, but still clings to the statistical data based on the *original* post. And continues to judge reviewers based on meaningless data. In other words: Reviewers see a post, but they are graded as if they had seen a different one. This both rewards reviewers lacking diligence, as well as penalizes those reviewers we want to do reviews.

There's really not much to say here: This is wrong<sup>1</sup>, no matter how you slice it, and needs to be fixed.

---

<sup>1</sup> Changing the context and expecting results to remain unchanged somehow reminded me of [this](https://youtu.be/dPOyOM7wxlE?t=1m17s).

Answer (score 6):

I see two problems:

1. When reviewing **with filters**, the system should **NOT** add your filtered tags to the audit question. No matters it's an **audit OR NOT**, the only law should be: one of the reviewed question's tags should match one of the OP's filtered tags. And that's that.
2. The system is currently assuming that on an audit **concerning content that is considered good** (a useful and up-voted question or answer), the only good actions to be taken is to up-vote or push "No action needed" or "Looks OK". Even with the tag screwing, sometimes (but very rarely) editing could be a good option. Maybe this option should send you directly to the original page instead of triggering the audit result.

Unless these two problems are solved, errors like these are going to happen again...