# Are review audits supposed to say they're audits?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, review-queues, review-audits

While going through the Triage queue, I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40125720/the-even-girl-over-the-age-of-60-have-used-this-product-and) little "gem" ([link to audit task](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14270884), provided by [rene](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/578411/rene) in the comments).  Feeling a bit bemused, I decided to leave a snarky comment before flagging it as spam.  Upon clicking "Add Comment", however, it gave me the error message "This is an audit".

...Is it just me, or does telling people that the post is an audit completely defeat the point of auditing people?

[image: Error: This is an audit.]

[We can't comment on audits](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272357/5386374), but this question is about the wisdom of outright *telling* people that it's an audit if they attempt to do so.

---

Note: Before anyone asks, I passed the audit, that's not what this is about.  I just don't think the "can't comment on audits" error message should outright say "This is an audit".

Comment: I assume you typed that comment for science, not to actually post it, right?   Before this users would fail an audit after they crafted a lengthy comment and in the process of being told they failed an audit they also lost that comment. I guess this is the *fix* to make the *leave comment* scenario less sucky for well meaning reviewers.

Comment: It would probably be better to have a link to the audit _task_, so that it can be viewed by non-10K users.

Comment: @StephenLeppik here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/14270884

Comment: @rene I figured that if it was an audit, it wouldn't go through anyways, and if it wasn't an audit, it'd at least get a chuckle from whoever got it in the Close Votes queue.  Didn't know that commenting on audits used to make you fail, though.

Comment: @StephenLeppik My bad, I didn't think of that.  I'll edit rene's link into the post, then.

Comment: Also, why is this tagged [bug]?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Not sure, I tagged it [discussion].  I guess someone else figured the error message was a bug.  Don't know whether I should change it back or not, since I'm not sure if the error message was intentional.

Comment: It was definitely intentional. Why would a bug produce results like that?

Comment: @StephenLeppik Looks like someone added a [status-bydesign] tag, so I'm guessing that means I shouldn't change it back to [discussion].

Comment: Fair enough, I guess.

Comment: Also, I'm going to attempt to leave a comment on the next audit that I find, just so that I can get that message.

Comment: When I commented, the audit passed.  So now you can just make a comment in case it's an audit, delete it 5 seconds later, and then proceed to not pay attention.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you're paying attention enough to leave a witty comment, then you're probably paying attention to what you're reviewing, meaning [the audit has done its job successfully.](/q/288046/6388243)

**See also:** [Cannot edit a comment in Review UI](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/270236/cannot-edit-a-comment-in-review-ui/286709#286709)

Comment: That's a good point.  I guess it doesn't matter if it admits to being an audit, if the reviewer is actually paying attention to it, then?

Comment: @JustinTime exactly.

Comment: I still think comments should act like normal, but not get submitted server-side.